# No functions in cv2

Tags: python

I can’t describe my problem, but when importing cv2 I don’t have all the functions of this module, I tried to install it in different ways, for example

```
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.62
pip install opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-python
```

None of the above helped.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH7sc.png)

I write the code in pycharm

Comment: try using a function and seeing if it actually works, it might just be a glitch in the auto fill menu

Comment: the functions don't work either